Using Realtec r8168 instead of r8169 with PCIe RTL8125B
I have a RTL8125B PCIe NIC in a computer running Ubuntu 24.04 server. An identical chipset NIC on the motherboard failed, hence the replacement. Unfortunately the PCIe NIC, unlike the motherboard counterpart, does not wake on LAN. I ensured the NIC supports wake on LAN, enabled the g flag using ethtool with a startup service that does this at boot, and made sure wake on LAN is on in the motherboard settings (not sure if a separate setting exists for "wake on PCI events", but I could not find it). The magic packet is definitely received as is evidenced by the nc command when the computer is on.
My last resort is to attempt to use the r8168 driver instead of r8169. I have read posts that claim this has solved certain issues for select users, including someone saying wake on LAN became possible (not sure if the Realtek chipset is identical in that case).
I ran sudo apt install r8168-dkms. Others have claimed this automatically replaced r8169 and blacklists it, though it hasn't for me. r8169 is still in use, and manually removing it with sudo rmmod r8169 and then attempting to load r8168 with sudo modprobe r8168 fails to bring the network interface that is lost after the rmmod command back up. Not sure what else to try. Is this driver incompatible with my model, or am I doing something wrong?
